# How to encode ConvertAPI secret while converting

Tags: security, encode, secret-key, convertapi

I am using convertAPI in angular as javascript
`let convertApi = ConvertApi.auth({ secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' });`
The secret is visible in the network tab but I want to make it secure.

So, I just want to make it encoded and I use `atob()` to encode it but convertAPI rejected the secret as it is not correct.
How can I secure the secret?

Answer (score 0):

Base64 will not help to hide your secret. If someone is looking for your secret, they will decode it. To secure your credentials you should use tokens.

```
let convertApi = ConvertApi.auth({ apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxx', token: 'xxxxxxx' });
```

Read more about the tokens: https://www.convertapi.com/doc/auth#token